# JSON+Javascript/jQuery. How to import data from a json file and parse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

If I have a `JSON` file named **names.json** with:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Meyers"},
    {"firstName":"Betty","lastName":"Layers"},
    {"firstName":"Carl","lastName":"Louis"},
]}
```

How can I use its content in javascript?

Comment: I had changed the question and fixed the errors. Now I think it could receive upvotes and would be a good reference to other people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An example how to do this could be:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON('names.json',function(data){
            console.log('success');
            $.each(data.employees,function(i,emp){
                $('ul').append('<li>'+emp.firstName+' '+emp.lastName+'</li>');
            });
        }).error(function(){
            console.log('error');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply include a Javascript file in your HTML that declares your JSON object as a variable. Then you can access your JSON data from your global Javascript scope using `data.employees`, for example.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

data.js:

```
var data = {
  "employees": [{
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Meyers"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Betty",
    "lastName": "Layers"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Carl",
    "lastName": "Louis"
  }]
}
```

Comment: You need to add this statement to file data.js :

""""  module.exports = data; """"

Otherwise you will not be able to import data variable value in any other file through data.js .

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON file does not contain valid JSON.  Try the following instead.

```
 {
     "employees": 
     [
         {
             "firstName": "Anna",
             "lastName": "Meyers"
         },
         {
             "firstName": "Betty",
             "lastName": "Layers"
         },
         {
             "firstName": "Carl",
             "lastName": "Louis"
         }
     ]
 }
```

You should then see a response. Check out http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: oh. yes. now works^^. Thx so much. I was thing the problem is in jquery code.

Comment: Specifically, the problem was the trailing comma in the employees area. JSON does not support trailing commas.

Answer (score 5):

In the jQuery code, you should have the `employees` property.

```
data.employees[0].firstName
```

So it would be like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("names.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('body').append(data.employees[0].firstName);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you'll need that property for the non jQuery version too, but you'd need to parse the JSON response first.

Also keep in mind that `document.write` is destroying your entire page.

---

If you're still having trouble, try the full `$.ajax` request instead of the `$.getJSON` wrapper.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "names.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('body').append(data.employees[0].firstName);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('ERROR', textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: hi cliffs, still not working to me. Can you post the entire code? The script was in head, but now is in the body and didn't work. =/

Comment: @GarouDan: Not sure what you mean when you say it doesn't work. Is the callback invoked at all? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer was given a long time ago, but this result is showing in first position on google.

However I don't want to use jquery, so in vanilla JS , [I found this quick tutorial](https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript) cleaner than senornestor answer (it also allow to load files depending on a variable) :

```
function loadJSON(filelocation, callback) {   

  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', filelocation, true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);  
}

function init() {
  var location = "myfile.json";
  loadJSON(filelocation=location,  function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string into object
    loadedJSON = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(loadedJSON.somethingsomething);
  });
}

init();
```

and on your html file:

```
`<script src="myscript.js"></script>`
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this without jQuery, you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). As of January 2023, it is supported by ~96% of browsers.

```
fetch("test.json").then(async (resp) => {
  const asObject = await resp.json();
  console.log(asObject);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP.

```
<?php
    $contents = file_get_contents('names.json');
?>
<script>
    var names = <?php echo $contents; ?>
    var obj = JSON.parse(names);

    //use obj
</script>
```

Optionally, use it async:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("get_json.php?file=names",function(obj){
            //use obj here          
        },'json');
    });
</script>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
    $filename = $_GET['file'] . '.json';
    $data['contents'] = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: The file already contains json, why json_encode what's already json? He could just get names.json directly without the last php wrapper.

Comment: Interesting solution xbonez. I will try a little using jQuery e javascript, but probably this solve my problem too.

Comment: And for what you are parsing fully-js object `names` to json `obj`. This not make sense like encoding json to... double json

Comment: Because when php reads it in using file_get_contents, it reads it in as a string. The string needs to be parsed to be available as a javascript object.