# Need to import JSON data to Simple html file

Tags: html, json

Is there a way to import some data from json file into html file.

In need to import some of these data to a html file, 
for example "Descrizione" and "Listino1" in a simple div.

Following is my json file sample:

```
[
 {
 "OP": "save",
 "DB_NAME": "plu",
 "ID": "005045",
 "Barcode": "",
 "CodVeloce": 0,
 "CodPv": 0,
 "FlagCondiviso": 1,
 "CodTaccuino": 0,
 "Descrizione": "BICC. VINO BIANCO",
 "Famiglia": "006",
 "ScortaMinima": 0,
 "Posizione": 181,
 "Reparto": 2,
 "CodImmagini": 0,
 "Listino1":4.00,
 "Listino2":4.00,
 "Listino3":0.00,
 "Listino4":0.00,
 "Stampante": 0,
 "Flag": 1,
 "Offerta": 0,
 "Colore": 19,
 "UnitMis": "",
 "CodFornitore": 0,
 "CodArtFornitore": "",
 "BarcodeConfezione": "",
 "PezziXConfezione": 0,
 "ForzaLavoro": 0,
 "PesoUnitario":0.00,
 "NumConfezioni": 0,
 "DescrizAggiuntiva": "",
 "OffertaAggiuntiva": 0,
 "PrezzoConfezione":0.00,
 "ColoreTac": 0,
 "Scala": 0,
 "DtVar": "2020/02/03" 
 },
```

Any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Please update your json data, it doesn't seem to be accurate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON+Javascript/jQuery. How to import data from a json file and parse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490473/jsonjavascript-jquery-how-to-import-data-from-a-json-file-and-parse-it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947608/how-to-display-json-in-html

Comment: that's the file i got

Comment: i'm newbie so maybe if it was a server it was a joke but with programming i'm really out of data